# What is the difference between milk and cream that causes disparate result when freezing and thawing?

Tags: phase, food-chemistry, melting-point

If you freeze milk and then let it thaw/melt again you just need to shake and it is more or less indistinguishable from unfrozen milk. That is not true for cream - after letting frozen cream (40 % fat) melt you have something quite similar to whipped cream in consistence. Why is cream different from milk in this situation?

Comment: Milk and whipping cream are different in most situations, similarly as beer and whiskey.

Comment: So this question is not about ice cream?

Comment: I've observed that too, cream that accidentially froze turns into a funny solid form after thawing. Not exactly like whipped cream, more rigid.  Is it crystallisation of fat, or something with the proteins? Good question.

Comment: @Poutnik What are you talking about? They are very similar except for the fat content.

Comment: @Karl, perhaps it's like what happens when one freezes tofu. It forms a spongy material, I think from the water being squeezed out during the freezing, which is tough and chewy enough to use directly as a meat substitute.

Comment: So maybe beer and whiskey doesn't work as analogy but instead Virgin Bloody Mary and Bloody Mary.

Comment: @d-b Bingo! It is quite a difference.

Comment: @Poutnik No, you can make milk from 40 % cream and cream from 2-3 % milk, just let it rest and separate. They are interchangeable (although in practise you would of course not do that).

Comment: @d-b You can make 1% NaCl solution from the saturated NaCl solution and vice versa either, what does not change the fact their properties are very different. // I am sure the milk prepared from 40% whipping cream would be different. // Freezing 40% cream helps ice/fat separation ( for milk as well, in lesse extent - thawn milk tastes differently), as even without freezing it the cream is at the edge of spontaneous separation. Similarly salt solution freezing separates water and salt as well and they like each other much more than fat and water.